# Event timing issue in browser extension

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, promise

I have a browser extension that automates an external website (which I have no control over and limited visibility into).

The site has a dropdown with three choices (not HTML `<select>`, but accomplished with ARIA and JS). I have verified that the Click event on a given element "drops down the box" (that is, adds HTML to the page to display the choices of the drop-down), and I have verified that clicking on a given element does indeed select it (I've done all this at the Chrome console prompt).

But when I try to combine it all into one piece of JS using promises to address event timing, it doesn't work. So given the following code:

```
function domEventPromise(elem, event) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        elem.addEventListener(event, () => resolve(true))
    })
}
function selectLastItem() {
    let perPageDropDown = document.querySelector('#podbookshelftable > div.mt-foot [role=button]');
    let perPageCurrValue = /^\d+/.exec(perPageDropDown.innerText);
    domEventPromise(perPageDropDown, 'click')
    .then(() => {
        let perPageMaxButton = perPageDropDown.querySelector('div.a-dropdown li:last-child a');
        if (!perPageMaxButton) debugger;
        let perPageMaxValue = /^\d+/.exec(perPageMaxButton.innerText);
        let numEntries = document.querySelector('table.podbookshelftable table.podbookshelftable').length;
        if (perPageCurrValue != perPageMaxValue) {
            perPageMaxButton.click();       // Click the last options; forces a page reload

            // Wait until we have more entries than before
            return retryUntilTrue(() => document.querySelector('table.podbookshelftable table.podbookshelftable').length > numEntries)
            .then(() => {
console.log("returning true(2) from displayingMaxASINs");
                return Promise.resolve(true);
            })
        } else {
console.log("returning true(3) from displayingMaxASINs");
            return Promise.resolve(true)
        }
    })
    .catch(handleError);
    perPageDropDown.click();        // Drop down the selector
}
```

What I'm doing is grabbing the current value of the dropdown, attaching a EventListener to the click event of the dropdown (so it should fire after the website's own click event handler fires and displays the dropdown in it's dropped state). The event handler then checks to see if the current value matches the maximum value; if not, then it clicks on the maximum value control (which causes some JS to fire and perform an AJAX call to refresh most of the page content), before exiting.

What's happening is that it runs to the point where the debugger call is, and then breaks at that point. Looking at the screen, the dropdown has not opened. If I then proceed from that point, it will end up in handleError, a message is displayed in the console indicating that we called "innerText" on a null value (i.e. perPageMaxButton is null). If I look at the screen at that point the dropdown has been activated and the "missing" element is now there. So this appears to be a timing problem with all the events that are firing. I tried setting a timeout loop retrying to see if the element appeared and it did not (that with a maximum of 100 1-second timeouts -- it does not take for 100 seconds in that scenario to get to the point where the debugger command fires and the dropdown is still not pulled down.

Comment: `function selectLastItem {` invalid syntax right there - so clearly you've posted code that isn't the code with the issue

Comment: the error suggests there's no element matching `div.a-dropdown li:last-child a` inside the element stored in `perPageDropDown` - without any HTML, the answer is a pineapple

Comment: If you can't find the element even after a timeout when you see it, it's not a timing issue, but rather a problem with the way you're trying to find the element.

Comment: @JaromandaX I actually just changed the function name to make it more readable in the submission.

Comment: you removed `()` to make it more readable? at the expense of showing valid code? interesting decision :p

Comment: @Nickolay Visually, the dropdown has not dropped down, even though the code that was designed to wait through the click event ran. I also tried this with code that would wait for the element to appear and it would never appear (visually or per the DOM). But the minute all of my code finished/gave up, the element appeared (visually and in the DOM). So it is an event timing issue. If I execute the click() command that you see at the console prompt, the dropdown drops down. If I then test for the element's existence, it exists. 1/2

Comment: What I am unable to accomplish is to put in some sort of wait state that allows the click() to actually run the event code that drops down the dropdown so that I can access the list. The fundamental question is, how do I "wait" for the code attached to the click() event to fully execute. I've tried a "then" (docs say that thens always run after the current event loop, which is what I was hoping for), I've tried multiple promise-based timeouts, and I can't find anything that will work.

Comment: No, that was a typo. Changing the name of the function I accidentally removed the ().

Comment: It's hard to guess what's the problem with your timeout without seeing the actual code. I would expect `setTimeout(function() { alert(perPageDropDown.querySelector('div.a-dropdown li:last-child a')) }, 1000);` to alert the element, based on your description.

Comment: I guess that the fundamental question is how to, in a promise-based environment, defer execution of a piece of code until all other code associated with element a's click() event fires and element b appears in the document. I tried two techniques: checking for element b's existence, then waiting a second (via a promise-based timeout call) and trying again up to 1000 times; and connecting a click() event handler to element a which (theoretically) ought to fire after any other click event handlers fire since it was the last to be attached. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 Both techniques finished rather quickly, but in neither case did the element appear on screen (I used a "debugger" command to pause execution after the element should have appeared). After I continued from the break, the element did appear, but of course my code was long since finished by then.